# Retrieving records from a table for a specific 24 hour time frame

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to pull an hourly value from a sql table, where the records have a UTC timestamp(7 Hours ahead of my local time) on them. The data I am trying to pull will have its total value as sum of values from 6 am today to 6 am tomorrow morning(local time). I was trying to use dateadd as below:

```
SELECT VALUES FROM TABLE1 WHERE TRANTIME BETWEEN
DATEADD(HOUR, 13, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE()))
AND
DATEADD(HOUR, 37, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE()))
```

The logic being that 6 am today morning is 13 hours from UTC midnight and tomorrow morning will be 37 hours since the previous dat midnight.

However the problem is when the UTC date rolls over, I dont have any data for the day lying in the between clause, since the UTC time is now like 00 or 01 hours.

I'm not sure how to handle this rolling of UTC date during the regular date.

Comment: I think you will have to get the difference between two consecutive days, i.e.11 hours in the first UTCdate and 13 hours in the next UTCdate.

Comment: What version of SQL-Server are you using? 2016 has this... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql

Comment: Its SQL 2014, I am not sure if we have this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is converting UTC to your local time first to ensure you're syncing on days initially and avoiding the rollover when your pulling in your local time:

```
SELECT VALUES FROM TABLE1 WHERE TRANTIME BETWEEN
DATEADD(HOUR, 13, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR,-7,GETUTCDATE()))
AND
DATEADD(HOUR, 37, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR,-7,GETUTCDATE()))
```